# How to zip files without creating directory inside zip directory?

Tags: ios, swift, zip, zipfoundation

I am trying to zip files at destination path. Everything works perfectly. My files are zipped at the destination URL. But the problem is when I unzip, my files are inside the directory. I don't want my files inside a directory. When I unzip, I want to see my files.

This is my code:

```
func zipData() {
    let  path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask,true).first!
    let fileManager = FileManager()

    var sourceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    sourceURL.appendPathComponent("/cropsapdb_up_\(useridsaved)")

    var destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    destinationURL.appendPathComponent("/cropsapdb_up_\(useridsaved).zip")
    do {
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: sourceURL.path)
        guard let archive = Archive(url: destinationURL, accessMode: .create) else  {
            print("returning")
            return
        }

        for item in items {
            sourceURL = sourceURL.appendingPathComponent("/\(item)")

            try archive.addEntry(with: sourceURL.lastPathComponent, relativeTo: sourceURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
            guard let archive = Archive(url: destinationURL, accessMode: .update) else  {
                print("returning")
                return
            }

            sourceURL.deleteLastPathComponent()
        }
    } catch {
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply move them programatically out of the directory and delete it when unzipping your file?

Comment: actually I send zip directory to the server. and at the server side directory is unziped.

Comment: Include a link to the zip library you are using.

Comment: https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation

Comment: I am zipping files at destination url.

Comment: By default, a root directory entry named after the lastPathComponent of the sourceURL is added to the destination archive. If you don't want to preserve the parent directory of the source in your archive, you can pass shouldKeepParent: false.

Comment: I tried that but still no effect.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am the author of [ZIP Foundation](http://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation), the library you are using.

If I understand your code correctly you want to recursively add the contents of a directory to a ZIP archive.
To achieve this, you can use the convenience method `zipItem` which is implemented as extension to `FileManager` in ZIP Foundation.
By default, it behaves like the Archive Utility on macOS and includes the last directory name of the `sourceURL` as root directory of the archive.  To alter that behaviour (as pointed out by Leo Dabus in the comments), you can pass the optional `shouldKeepParent: false` parameter:

```
func zipData() {
    let useridsaved = 1
    
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask,true).first!
    var sourceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    sourceURL.appendPathComponent("cropsapdb_up_\(useridsaved)")
    var destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    destinationURL.appendPathComponent("cropsapdb_up_\(useridsaved).zip")
    do {
        try fileManager.zipItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL, shouldKeepParent: false)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

(I added a fictional `let useridsaved = 1` local variable to make your sample compilable)

To verify that the archive does indeed not include a root directory, you can use the `zipinfo` command line utility shipping with macOS.
It is also possible, that the ZIP code on your server implicitly creates a directory when unpacking your archive.

Comment: There are two files at my sourceurl. One is jpg image and other is csv file.                                                                                                 
 When I try like this :   try fileManager.zipItem(at: sourceURL, to:destinationURL,shouldKeepParent: false) .                                                                                                                    I get  error :   NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “1_1.jpg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Comment: when I do like this :  try fileManager.zipItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL) .  My both files are zipped at destination url but it includes root directory.

Comment: What version of the library are you using?
0.9.4 had a bug related to `shouldKeepParent`. This got fixed in 0.9.5

Comment: I am using  pod 'ZIPFoundation', '~> 0.9'

Comment: And did you update the library to 0.9.5 via `pod update`?

Comment: I updated my library to 0.9.5.  and try like this:           try fileManager.zipItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL,shouldKeepParent: false) .     Now it doesn't show any error but it still creating root directory.

Comment: How do you verify that it creates a root directory? If you use the default macOS Archive Utility to extract, it will always put the results in a folder named like your Archive zip. E.g. if the resulting zip file is named xy.zip, Archive Utility will create a folder "xy" containing the contents of xy.zip. This depends on the utility you use to extract the file and _not_ the ZIP library. To verify the actual structure of your archive, you can use the zipinfo command line utility within Terminal.

Comment: Yes , I am using default macOS Archive Utility to extract. I will try using zipinfo command line utility within Terminal.

Comment: Hi, I have a question regarding zipping. Is it possible to create a zip in memory instead of creating in the disk? If yes please give me an idea?

Comment: There is a pull request open to add this functionality to ZIP Foundation: https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation/pull/78
Reading from in-memory archive already works. Writing has some issues though.

Comment: Is it support multiple file zip? Please suggest me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can add multiple files to an archive. There are several ways to do so - either via the `addEntry` API, or by using the higher level `FileManager` extension.